# How to re-loop a setInterval/setTimeout function

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, settimeout, setinterval

I am trying to re-loop the display of user-inputted string. I am doing this using either setInterval or setTimeout (not sure which one)

So if a user submits 2 entries into a text-box form, those 2 entries will be displayed, one after another, repeatedly.

What follows is my code, taken from: jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/sKadX/4/

```
frm.submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    container.push(txtBox.val());

    var i = 0;

    function myLoop(){
        setInterval(function () {
            output.text(container[i]);
            i++;
            if (i < container.length) {
                myLoop();
            }
        }, 3000)
    }

    myLoop();

    txtBox.val('');
});
```

As my code is now, if you input 2 different strings into the form, one after another, it will display one after the other (w/ a delay), but then it will stop at the last one (it won't re-loop).

How would I fix the code to get it to continuously re-loop the input so that it doesn't stop at the last inputted string, but instead restart at and display the 1st inputted string? (This should hopefully also work for more than 2 inputs. For example, if a user inputs 5 different entries, then it will loop thru and display those 5 over and over again)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've modified your fiddle a bit. Now the `frm.submit` event looks like:

```
frm.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    container.push(txtBox.val());
    var i = 0; // to initialize the index
    clearInterval(oldHandle); //to make sure only one setInterval is running at any time
    oldHandle = setInterval(function () {
        output.text(container[i]);
        i++;
        if (i == container.length) { //this re-loops your container array once the last element is reached 
            i = 0; //reset the index
        }
    }, 500)

    txtBox.val('');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/sKadX/6/)

Edit: For your follow-up question, I've `splice`d the `container` array with the index of the `p` tag clicked(using jQuery's `prevAll`)

```
$(".controlbox").on('dblclick', 'p', function () {
        container.splice($(this).prevAll('p').length, 1);
        $(this).remove();
});
```

I've also modified the `frm.submit` event, now it looks like:

```
oldHandle = setInterval(function () {
    output.text(container[i++%container.length]);
}, 500)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/sKadX/12/)

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Follow up question: I've added an event handler that allows for the removal of entries from my control panel by double clicking on the entry (this happens after entries have been inputted to the array). However, this doesn't remove the entry from the container-Array. Any advice as to how to bind/link the event handler so that removal of an entry from the control panel ALSO RESULTS IN THE REMOVAL OF THAT ENTRY FROM THE ARRAY? http://jsfiddle.net/sean1rose/sKadX/9/

Comment: @Seeeyonnn You can use `splice` to remove the value selected, using its index. See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/sKadX/11/) (do consider using a [select/multiSelect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) though, instead of this `.container>p` structure)

Comment: @Seeeyonnn Update: `multiselect` [reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp). See the `select[multiple]` in action in the second fiddle I've posted in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
frm.submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  container.push(txtBox.val());
  console.log(container);
  function myLoop(){
    setInterval(function () {
        var str="";
        for(var i=0;i<container.length;i++){
           str+=container[i]+"<br>";

        }
        output.html(str)
        myLoop();
    }, 3000)
}

myLoop();

txtBox.val('');
});
```

fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/tCw8Q/